# Angular ui layout - how to set width dynamicaly

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui, jquery-ui-layout

In the angular-ui-layout module, to set the size we need to pass a value like `<div ui-layout-container size='20%'>` is it possible to pass a model, so when ever model value gets changed, the size of the panel should also change.

Expecting:

```
<input ng-model='sizeModel' type='number'/>
<div ui-layout-container size='sizeModel'>
```

OR how to set open & close of a pane on button click event instead of clicking on small arrows in the divider?

Comment: Have you tried doing this? What happened? And please use a different post for multiple questions

Comment: I'm trying to.. but no luck..
I guess I should build my own directive :(

Comment: Having the same problem. Any conclusion?

Comment: @nitech I have implemented my own directive,  to resize & to collapse :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried put variable in brackets?

```
<div ui-layout-container size='{{sizeModel}}'>
```